# Why is there a significant difference in the output image on changing the ddepth parameter for Sobel operator?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, edge-detection

I was trying edge detection with `OpenCV` and got confused with the `ddepth` parameter when applying the `Sobel` operator. When the `ddepth` of the output image is kept the same as the original image which is `CV_8U` in this case, I get the output as

[image]

for the original image

[image]

but when the `ddepth` parameter is kept as `CV_64F` the output image looks as

[image]

Could you help me understand what is happening here?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("valve.png", 0)

sobelx3_64 = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)

sobelx3_8 = cv2.Sobel(img, -1,1,0,ksize=3)

cv2.imshow("sobelx3_64", sobelx3_64)

cv2.imshow("sobelx3_8", sobelx3_8)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two causes for the difference:

- First is the display. Opencv's imshow will only consider values between (0,1) for float type images and (0,255) for uint8 type images. Any values greater than 1 will be treated as 1 for float images. That's why you see majority of the image become white. you can fix it by `cv2.imshow("sobelx3_64", sobelx3_64/255)` i.e normalize it within (0,1) (but look at the second point, this is not entirely correct).
- `print(sobelx3_8[0:3,0:3]);print(sobelx3_64[0:3,0:3])`. This produces the following. Now they are different because of range, sobel operator's actual value is greater than 255 but uint8 type cannot fit in 480, so opencv will saturate it to 255. Similarly for negative values.

Output.

```
[[  0 200 255]
 [  0 131 255]
 [  0   0 255]]
[[   0.  200.  480.]
 [   0.  131.  425.]
 [   0.   -4.  316.]]
```